# How can I flip rows from one table into columns of a second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I take a row value from table FormField and create a column in table Registrant? Somehow it also needs to be smart enough to know if the column already exists.

Essentially I am flipping rows from the 1st table into columns on the 2nd table.

What I have right now was manually entered. However I need to code it to do this. Would this be a trigger or how would I even properly do this?

FormField table contains column ColumnName, one example of a row being FirstName.

[image]

Registrant table contains columns that should correspond, such as column FirstName

[image]

It needs to be "fool-proof" because if someone else enters FirstName into ColumnName, it shouldn't try to add another FirstName column. This also means it should reformat the string to work as a proper column (proper case, no spaces, etc).

Comment: My approach would be to use system tables like those found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx to query your source table and exclude any existing columns.  I would then use a procedure to to alter the table to add the necessary new fields.  The problem you have is you don't know the datatype or field size precision and if it's nullable or not based on your source data.  So I don't see how you can accomplish this to be 'fool-proof'  What rubs me wrong here is you're changing structure on the fly.  And that just never seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks. I should probably add some fields to FormField to collect the data type, size, and nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate ALTER TABLE commands for missing fields. "Fool-proofing" should be done beforehand:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [Registrant] ADD [' + [ColumnName] + '] NVARCHAR(MAX);' 
FROM [FormField] f
        LEFT JOIN syscolumns c ON OBJECT_NAME(c.id) = 'Registrant' 
                              AND c.Name = f.[ColumnName]
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. I see you are adding NVARCHAR(MAX). Is there a way I can collect that info from my other table? I could add datatype and null fields to FormField table and then somehow reference it in your ALTER TABLE code.

Comment: Yes, if you added the required fields to FormField then you can use them to build up the UPDATE string by concatenating it in such as I did with the [ColumnName] field.